# PHP assign result from nested query into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, temp-tables, subquery

I need help in order to assign the results of a nested query into array. This is the scenario:

```
$Date_Collection = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM TblDate");

while($date = mysql_fetch_array($Date_Collection)) // Loop through all the dates
{
    $var_date = $date['Date'];
    $result = mysql_query("select min(Speed) as Min_spd, max (Speed) as Max_spd, avg   
                  (Speed) as Avg_spd from ... where Date= $var_date");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
     echo "row[Min_spd]";
     echo "row[Max_spd]";
     echo "row[Avg_spd]";
    }
 }
```

The output from this query is like this:

```
Min_Spd |Max_Spd |Avg_Spd|       Date|
    12.0|    25.0|   20.4| 2012-10-01|
    11.0|    28.0|   21.4| 2012-10-02|
    10.0|    26.0|   23.4| 2012-10-05|
    08.0|    22.0|   21.4| 2012-10-08|
```

I basically need to show the sum of Min_Spd, Sum of Max_spd, Sum of Avg_spd for all these dates. So, I thought that If I can assign these values into an array and later compute these sum from the array, it might be a good idea.

Can anyone please help me regarding this? Can I use an array to store the values and later access these values and calculate the sum of these values. If I can use an array, could anyone please show me the syntax of using array in PHP. I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Is there any alternative way rather than using an array, such as creating a temporary table to save these values and later delete the temporary table. If a temporary table can be used, could you please show me how to do that. I could use the temptable for a single loop, but there is a nested loop and I don't exactly know what to do to create a temp table inside the nested loop to store all the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

then later on you can do

```
foreach($data as $row) {
   echo $row['Min_spd'];
   echo ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the MySQL [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function can be used to do that on te query, try it. But on this example, using arrays you should store the values and then use [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to return the sum of the elements. Something like this:

```
$min_spd = array();
$max_spd = array();
$avg_spd = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $min_spd[] = $row['Min_spd'];
    $max_spd[] = $row['Max_spd'];
    $avg_spd[] = $row['Avg_spd'];
}

echo array_sum($min_spd);
```

It can also be done using variables to store and add the values:

```
$min_spd = 0;
$max_spd = 0;
$avg_spd = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $min_spd += $row['Min_spd'];
    $max_spd += $row['Max_spd'];
    $avg_spd += $row['Avg_spd'];
}

echo $min_spd;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all save yourself a nested query by doing the first query as:

```
$result = mysql_query("select Date, min(Speed) as Min_spd, max (Speed) as Max_spd, avg(Speed) as Avg_spd from ... group by Date")
```

And then create a running total for the sums as you're looping through each row:

```
$sumMinSpeeds=0;
$sumMaxSpeeds=0;
$sumAvgSpeeds=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo row['Min_spd'];
    echo row['Max_spd'];
    echo row['Avg_spd'];

    $sumMinSpeeds += $row['Min_spd'];
    $sumMinSpeeds += $row['Max_spd'];
    $sumMinSpeeds += $row['Avg_spd'];

}
echo $sumMinSpeeds;
echo $sumMaxSpeeds;
echo $sumAvgSpeeds;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing several MySQL queries in a loop, consider constructing such a query, which will return all the results you need.

**SQL**

First of all, it would make sense to use the [`GROUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) SQL construct.

```sql
SELECT
    s.Date       date,
    MIN(s.Speed) min,
    MAX(s.Speed) max,
    AVG(s.Speed) avg
FROM speed_table s
WHERE s.Date IN (SELECT DISTINCT d.Date FROM date_table d)
GROUP BY s.Date
```

It is important to understand what each part of this query does. If you run into any problems, consult the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/).

**PHP**

Forget about using `mysql_*` functions: they are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and better implementations have emerged: [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). My example uses `PDO`.

```php
try {
    $dbh = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=my_db_name;host=127.0.0.1', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql  = '...';  // This is the query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

You can now either iterate over the returned result set

```php
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("%s; %s; %s; %s\n", $row['date'], $row['min'], $row['max'], $row['avg']);
}
```

or have the `Statement` object return the whole array by using

```php
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try as you suggested.